# Facebook SDK Upload a video - android application

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to upload video to Facebook and get back video_id after the success response.

Until the 1.8.2018 we used share dialog for upload video to user timeline and it worked fine, we got the video_id.

but 
[Facebook decided to stop enable return postIDs](https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/169222300585670/?disable_redirect=0)

So there is a way that used to upload a video to Facebook and get the video_id?
How to do it?